# Which has better performance, saving rest response to text via JSON.stringify or converting response to text?

Tags: javascript, json, performance, rest, puppeteer

I am saving millions of json objects into text files from puppeteer response listener. Which option has better performance and is regarded as best practice.

Option 1 - with JSON.stringify

```
//puppeteer listener
page.on("response", async response => {

   let jsonResponse = await response.json();

   await fs.writeFileSync(
      "1.json",
      JSON.stringify(jsonResponse)
   );

})
```

Option 2 - with converting response to text

```
page.on("response", async response => {

   let jsonTextResponse = await response.text();

   await fs.writeFileSync(
      "2.json",
      jsonTextResponse
   );

})
```

Comment: I'd bet a lot that `jsonTextResponse` is better - it doesn't involve any serialization or deserialization parsing, so it's cheaper. (but, you may want to verify that the response *is* proper JSON, else you might be writing corrupt data)

Comment: If the response is JSON text originally and all you want to do is store it as JSON again then there's no point deserialising and then re-serialising it again immediately afterwards - that's just redundant because after those two operations you end up with exactly what you started with. So I'd go for the text option. But I seriously doubt you'll see any really noticeable performance difference unless there's a lot of data in the response

Comment: I mentioned it is a puppeteer listener, hence it returns this response class,

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-response


thanks for the tip to confirm if its proper json, can you confirm whether response.text() would be faster, there are millions of files being processed and every little bit counts, thanks @CertainPerformance